# A composable with a card and children objects that fits all types of screens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have made a Card with children objects inside that should be placed in 3 rows, on under eachother. However this card and its children does not adapt to the different screens. As an example, when I launch the app on an emulator it looks decent but not when I launch it on my phone (S9). How can I make it adapt the view/Card for each screen?

Appreciate any feedback!

https://gyazo.com/b7f3bead14625d997322b6e6388b2011

```
@Composable
fun MainCardComposable() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        TopImage()

        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()

        ) {
            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,) {

                CentralWrittenText()
            }

        }


        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            CardDemo2()

        }
    }
}
```

Card composable:

```
@Composable
fun CardDemo2() {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 100.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(40.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
        border = BorderStroke(15.dp, Color.White),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(40.dp)
    ) {

        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.item1,
                    text = "Item1",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 40.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,
                    onClick = {}
                )

                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.Item2,
                    text = "Item2",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 40.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,
                    onClick = {}
                )


                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.Item3,
                    text = "Item3",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 40.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,
                    onClick = {}
                )


            }


            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {

                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.Item4,
                    text = "Item4",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 150.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,
                    onClick = {}
                )

                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.Item5,
                    text = "Item5",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 150.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,

                    onClick = {}
                )


                SelectionRoundCircle(
                    image = R.drawable.Item6,
                    text = "Item6",
                    paddingLeft = 35.dp,
                    paddingTop = 150.dp,
                    paddingRight = 35.dp,
                    onClick = {}
                )


            }
}
```

SelectionRoundCircle:

```
@Composable
fun SelectionRoundCircle(
    image: Int,
    text: String,
    paddingTop: Dp,
    paddingLeft: Dp,
    paddingRight: Dp,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit
) {

    Box(
        Modifier
            .padding(start = paddingLeft, top = paddingTop, end = paddingLeft)
    )
    {

        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {

            Image(
                painterResource(
                    id = image,
                ),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(55.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .border(1.dp, greyForSelectionCircles, CircleShape)
                    .clickable {
                        // Click event here
                    }
                    .wrapContentSize(),
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))

            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                )
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Kindly add some screenshots to understand the issue better.

Comment: for that you have to make your screen adaptive, in jetpack compose there are several ways you can know the screen width and height 1. WindowSizeClass 2.BoxWithConstraints 3.Create a custom layout using Layout composable. Read the docs : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive

Comment: I have added a screenshot as requested! @Abhimanyu

Comment: I am mostly interested in different types of phones but I suppose it is the same principle!  Thanks @zaidkhan